# Quiero insertarle texto a una etiqueta H1 en Js pero cuando lo hago se borran las demás etiquetas hijo

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
    <h1>
      <img name="imagencita" />
      <p class="parrafito"><a class="enlacito"><a class="enlacito"></a></p>
      <p class="parrafito"></p>
    </h1>
  
    <script>
    let h1s = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
        //Bucle para rellenar todos los h1 del documeno
    for (let index = 0; index < h1s.length; index++) {
        let texto = document.createAttribute("p");
        h1s[index].textContent = "Esto es un h1";
        
    }
    </script>
```

El problema es que cuando lo inserto me borra las etiquetas que ya habían dentro de este h1 y ni con innertext ni con innerhtml se quedan las etiquetas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te borra los demás elementos porque lo que hace tu código es una asignación, básicamente sobreescribes lo que ya existía por lo nuevo. Podrías usar [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) (hay un ejemplo muy similar en la documentación) para conservar el contenido anterior. Otra recomendación sería no colocar esas etiquetas dentro de un `<h1>`, mejor encalupa todo dentro de un `<div>`, preferiblemente que el h1 sea solo texto.

Comment: Dentro del for, prueba poniendo esta línea `let texto = document.createTextNode("Esto es un h1");` y debajo pon `h1s[index].appendChild(texto);`, reemplazando por lo que tenías dentro del for antes.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí solucionarlo así:
En la variable "tempo" le doy todo el contenido html(Etiquetas Hijo) que puede tener el h1.
ej:

Mi h1 con el valor:

```
<h1><a href="inicio"/></h1>
```

```
 let tempo = h1s[index].innerHTML
```

y luego inserto dentro de ese h1 el texto "Esto es un h1" concatenando además todas las etiquetas que este tenía antes.
´´´
h1s[index].innerHTML = "Esto es un h1"+tempo;
´´´

Si solo pusiéramos el "Esto es un h1" se sobrescribiría todo lo que hubiese dentro del h1.
Ej:

```
<h1>Esto es un h1</h1>
```

y de esta manera lo aplico a todos las etiquetas del documento

```
 let h1s = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
        //Bucle para rellenar todos los h1 del documento
    for (let index = 0; index < h1s.length; index++) {
        let tempo = h1s[index].innerHTML
        h1s[index].innerHTML = "Esto es un h1"+tempo;
        
    }
```

Comment: y esto en qué cambia?... iría bien una explicación...

Answer (score 0):

Como tu pregunta carece de explicación sobre cómo exactamente querés, te comparto dos forma de realizar.

Primero, seleccionamos todos los `p` con la clase parrafito con `querySelectorAll`, y ahí le escribimos lo que sea: si es texto: `innerText`; o si será algo más como etiquetas: `innerHTML`

```js
            
let h1s = document.querySelectorAll(".parrafito");
     
for (let index = 0; index < h1s.length; index++) {
    
    h1s[index].innerHTML = "Esto es un h1";
    
}
```

```html
            
<h1>
  <img name="imagencita" title="foto" />
  <p class="parrafito"><a class="enlacito"><a class="enlacito">enlace</a></p>
  <p class="parrafito"></p>
</h1>
```

La segunda opción es seleccionar todos los `h1` con clase o ID `miH1` en insertamos una plantilla predefinida en javascript:

```js
            
let h1s = document.querySelectorAll("#miH1");

// Esta plantilla se inserta en el H1
const template = `

<img name="imagencita" title="foto" />
<p class="parrafito">Primer parrafo con <a href="#" class="enlacito">enlace</a></p>
<p class="parrafito">Segundo parrafo</p>

`;        

for (let index = 0; index < h1s.length; index++) {
    
    h1s[index].innerHTML = template;
    
}
```

```html
            
<h1 ID="miH1">
  <img name="imagencita" />
  <p class="parrafito"><a class="enlacito"><a class="enlacito">enlace</a></p>
  <p class="parrafito"></p>
</h1>
```